# Convert CSV file to array of json objects with Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a CSV file where each row represents a json object. I'm attempting to convert this to a file that contains an array of json objects.

I should say up front that I am not a seasoned Python developer.

Example data in CSV file with 2 entries:

```
{"first_name": "Jason", "last_name": "Elwood", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"}, "occupation": "developer"}

{"first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Plumb", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"}, "occupation": "plumber"}
```

[image]

Desired output:

```
[{
        "first_name": "Jason",
        "last_name": "Elwood",
        "last_modified": {
            "type": "/type/datetime",
            "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"
        },
        "occupation": "developer"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Joe",
        "last_name": "Plumb",
        "last_modified": {
            "type": "/type/datetime",
            "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"
        },
        "occupation": "plumber"
    }
]
```

Here is some Python code which approximates what I'm attempting to do (for demonstration, first I print a local json formatted string, and then I print from the read CSV file:

python:

```
# Python3
# read CSV file to array of json objects
  
# initializing string 
test_string = '{"first_name": "Jason", "last_name": "Elwood", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"}, "occupation": "developer"}' 

print("test_string:")
print(test_string)

arr = []
arr.append(str(test_string))
# printing original string 
print("Array from test_string :")
print(arr)

arr = []
with open('testData.csv') as f:
    for row in f:
        arr.append(row)
    print("Array from file:")
    print(arr)
```

Here is the output:

```
test_string:
{"first_name": "Jason", "last_name": "Elwood", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"}, "occupation": "developer"}
Array from test_string :
['{"first_name": "Jason", "last_name": "Elwood", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856"}, "occupation": "developer"}']
Array from file:
['"{""first_name"": ""Jason"", ""last_name"": ""Elwood"", ""last_modified"": {""type"": ""/type/datetime"", ""value"": ""2008-08-20T17:57:46.368856""}, ""occupation"": ""developer""}"']
```

a. The hard-coded string prints just fine: i.e. a valid json formatted string.

b. Once added to an array, the hard-coded string is surrounded in single quotes.

c. The csv imported string however is being surrounded in quotes and all preexisting quotes are being duplicated.

To reiterate, I would like an array of json objects that can be easily imported into a NoSQL db.

Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if I can offer any more information that will help describe my present, and desired result.

Thanks in advance, and have a great day!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the JSON module here?

Comment: Thanks, @tdelaney. Added.

Comment: `for row in f: arr.append(row)` this just appends _each line_ of `f` to `arr`. To convert it to an object, you need to _parse the line into an object first!_ Look up `json.loads()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering, "Test.csv" is the CSV file name which is having your 2 entries. Please
find code to dump data to JSON file("Test.json").

```py
import csv
import json


def main():
    # Read Test csv having 2 records
    with open("Test.csv") as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        result = [json.loads(record[0]) for record in data]

    # dump csv data to Test.json file
    with open("Test.json", "w") as jsonfile:
        json.dump(result, jsonfile)
    
    # read Test json file to validate data is dumped correctly or not
    with open("Test.json", "r") as jsonfile:
        data = json.loads(jsonfile.read())
        for record in data:
            print(record)
            
main()
```

Comment: Thank you, Vimlesh! This seems to have done it. I appreciate your time on this. You have saved me a lot of time banging my head against my desk. :)

Comment: So this approach has worked for my use case, but now I have a question about JSONDecodeError Exceptions. Is there a way to skip records that are not formatted correctly? For example I'd like to be able to catch this exception when it is raised and skip the faulty row and just keep copying the file, omitting any badly formatted rows. Thanks!

Comment: result = [json.loads(record[0]) for record in data], this line i have written using list comprehension. you can write it as normal for loop and inside for loop, write try and expect block. if it is exception, just continue for loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a CSV file. Its a bunch of line separated json records. You don't want to try to process it as a CSV because all of those commas will be treated as column separators.

```
import json
with open("testfile.jsons") as fileobj:
    result = [json.loads(record) for record in fileobj]
```